# why can;t I open my php file on localhost?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Retreat Reservation System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Retreat Reservation System</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Branches</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
<?php
// Database credentials
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'easeltd';

// Connect to database
$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . !$connection->connect_error);
}
//read all rows
$sql= "SELECT * FROM branch";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if (!$result){
die("Invalid query: ". $connection->error);
}

//read data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row["branch_id"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["branch_name"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["adderess"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["phone_number"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["branch_id"] . "</td>
</tr>";
}
?>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Rooms</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Room 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Room 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Room 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Bookings</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Booking 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Booking 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Booking 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Suppliers</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Supplier 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supplier 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supplier 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 Retreat Reservation System</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is a php file, and I am using using xampp server. when I type localhost/easeltd in the url box i get this error:[image]

these are my database details:
[image]

I want to see details of my 'branch' table:[image]

does someone here understand the situation and help me change the code or do some kind of tweaking to get my code running? thanks?

Comment: please add more context to your question.

Comment: Why do you think the path `/easeltd` would run this file?

Comment: @tkausl I was watching youtube clip, the person in the cvideo did the same thing. he wrote /localhost/dbname

Comment: @VladUlshin, for example, where branch 2 is written, the code above should print the data ffrom branch table. when i write localhost/easeltd, I get the error that I mentioned above

Comment: You need to set up your PHP web root and put your PHP files In that *exact* location.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. A YouTube "tutorial" is the worst place to start.

Comment: IMHO w3schools is an ok place to start, if you want to use PHP "raw" in Apache, without frameworks.

Comment: You wrote: "the person in the cvideo did the same thing. he wrote /localhost/dbname". You miss understood that. This is not how things work. You request a php script with your browser. That script might use a connection to the database server. So you need to reference the php script in the URL the browser requests, not a database name.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the branches page and then make the login page, it will not work. You must first make the login page. If that doesn't work, check the database or XAMPP. Sometimes the problem can be with XAMPP, especially if you are using Windows OS.